# При прокрутке слайдера под текущим слайдом появляется следующий/предыдущий слайд, нет плавной смены слайдов. Как исправить?

Tags: bootstrap4, слайдер

На страницу добавлен слайдер при помощи Bootstrap 4. При прокрутке слайдов вперед или назад, следующий или предыдущий слайд появляется внизу под текущим, движется, исчезает и встает в сам слайдер. Высота страницы при этом меняется: когда слайд появляется - высота увеличивается, когда исчезает и слайд встает на своё место - уменьшается. Как это убрать? Это происходит независимо от размера изображений, их количества и повтора(например, все изображения слайдера одинаковые.

Код слайдера:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide bg-black" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item bg-black active">
                            <img class="d-block" src="img/slider-top/22.jpg" alt="Первый слайд">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item bg-black">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/slider-top/222.jpg" alt="Второй слайд">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item bg-black">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/slider-top/2.jpg" alt="Третий слайд">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
</div>
```

Стили слайдера:

```
.carousel {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
}
.carousel-item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px; /* высота изображения */
    object-fit: cover;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin-top: 10%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    bottom: -30px;
}
.carousel-control-prev {
    left: -120px;
}
.carousel-control-next {
    right: -120px;
}
```

Comment: Пробовали оболочке слайдера, в которой возникает элемент прокрутки, задать максимальную высоту и `overflow: hidden`, чтоб блок не увеличивался, а полоса прокрутки не возникала?

Comment: На странице имеется контент, кроме слайдера, и полоса прокрутки должна быть. У контейнера слайдера не появляется полосы прокрутки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте фрагмент кода, так, чтоб его можно было запустить и посмотреть из-за чего возникает баг. Часть стилей идет из бутстрапа и сложно сказать где баг

Comment: Проблема была решена! Дело оказалось в:
`.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
}`
После удаления данного свойства слайдер заработал как положено.